# Accessible references on singular homology and de Rham's theorem

Tags: algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology

I am taking part in an undergraduate seminar on manifolds and am to do a talk on de Rham's theorem. My exposition should follow and be on the level of the corresponding chapter of Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds". While I am to cover only de Rham's theorem in my talk, I would like to (and need to) properly understand singular homology, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence (both for the singular homology and the DR cohomology) and other related concepts (smooth homotopies, homotopy invariance of the DRC, the proof of de Rham's theorem, etc). While Lee's book is rather accessible and in general a good reference, I like having a couple more on hand for cross-referencing concepts and ideas I don't initially understand in one book or the other.

My background includes an introductory topology course (including the fundamental group and some algebraic topology) and an introductory manifolds course (comparable to Lee's or Tu's books on smooth manifolds). I am already using Lee's "Introduction to Topological Manifolds" as a reference on singular homology. Are there any others you could recommend?

Comment: I like Fulton's Intro to Algebraic Topology because he does all this stuff but only with open sets in the plane, so it's actually all understandable before the abstraction happens.

Comment: There's a nice simultaneous discussion of singular homology and de Rham cohomology, which emphasizes their duality and culminates in de Rham's theorem, in Conlon's Differentiable Manifolds. Two caveats are that a) he only ever uses smooth simplices and so doesn't discuss the true singular homology, but the comparison of those two is carried out in detail in Lee's book and b) he doesn't prove the M-V sequence for singular homology (and neither does Lee), but you can find that discussed in any algebraic topology textbook (e.g. [this one](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf)).

Comment: The book Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology, by Bott and Tu may be a good start. Now, if you have the time, I recommend Chapter 8 of Spivak's classic book, Volume I.

Comment: @Laz I'd taken a brief look at Bott and Tu some time ago, I think the book would be too tough for me. I'll take a look at Spivak.

Comment: @Randall,@Thorgott thanks for the recs, I'll check both out.